# Problem reading email only from firebase php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to reach any e-mail in this collection, but I did not know

i try to right
 `$document->data()['email']`
but give me this error
[image: Email can't read]
my firebase
[image: Firebase]

my code is :

```
public function index()
{
    $factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount(__DIR__ . '/autocar-f28fb-firebase-adminsdk-h8yrz-96c611a72e.json')
        ->createFirestore()->database()->collection('users')->documents()->rows();

    foreach ($factory as $document) {
        echo $document->data()['email'];
        foreach ($document->data() as $data => $value) {
            // here try to access but i can't;
        }
        printf(PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just debug your code, dump your `$factory` variable to see what it contains. By the way, don't call it `$factory`, it contains a collection of documents.

Comment: it contains array of data but i want just email from this data

Comment: If you dont know what `$document` look like then `print_r($document)` or var_dump() it anything so you can see what you are trying to process. Unless of course you are using a debugger, then it should be easy to work out what the collection actually looks like

Comment: I know what is inside the document, and I output it by ```print_r```, but when I want to specify the data inside it, for example, inside the e-mail opinion, I cannot

Answer (score 0):

Your error message, **"Undefined array key 'email'"** implies that the `email` key is not present in the array returned by `$document->data()`. You can try including an `isset()` function on your code to verify if the `email` key exists before accessing it. This will prevent the "Undefined array key" error from occurring.

For example:

```
foreach ($factory as $document) {
        $data = $document->data();
        if (isset($data['email'])) {
            echo $data['email'];
        } else {
            echo "Email not found";
        }
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            // Access other data in the document
        }
        printf(PHP_EOL);
```